# Allow a user access to 2 specific pages using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where users must log in to access pages. When they are not logged in I redirect them to the log in page and it then sets a cookie / token. I know this is not the most stable way of doing it but it works and its not a high traffic site whatsoever. maybe 5 users. My issue now is I need to give the users access to a contact us page even if the cookie / token is not set / valid. I tried to add another conditional to the function but it creates an infinite loop. Any ideas of handling this situation?

jQuery :

```
 function checkIfTokenExists() {
    var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    var logInToken = _siteNs.Utils.readCookie('SST');

    if (!logInToken) {
      if (current_url != '/login.html') {
        window.location.replace('/login.html');
      }
    } else if (logInToken) {
      _siteNs.authenticateUtils.authenticateSite();
    }
  }
```

What I would like is if url is equal to /contact.html the users will be able to access regardless of cookie / token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can early return before the token check, if the current URL is the contact page.

```
function checkIfTokenExists() {
    var current_url = window.location.pathname;
    var logInToken = _siteNs.Utils.readCookie('SST');

    if (current_url == '/contact.html') {
        return;
    }

    // ... rest of your code
```